# Metadata file **.DataAccess\bin\Debug\**.DataAccess.exe could not be found

Tags: visual-studio, metadata

I work in Visual Studio 2013. 
Project **.DataAccess in a reference project in my main project. 
I got an error:

```
Metadata file **.DataAccess\bin\Debug\**.DataAccess.exe could not be found
```

Why does Visual Studio look for this file? How can I fix it?

- I checked all Build boxes and restart Visual Studio as well

Comment: does your DataAccess project build?

Comment: no, when I build I get two errors. The following one and second: The type 'Telerik.OpenAccess.SPI.dataobjects.PersistenceCapable' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't build the DataAccess project then there is no .exe in the bin\Debug folder to reference.  So you need to fix that one first.

And by your comment that one needs a reference to

```
'Telerik.OpenAccess.SPI.dataobjects.PersistenceCapable'
```

in order to build.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't spend hours to solve this error. The real problem was that  I had "Output type" set to Window Application instead of Class Library. (and also luck of telerik references)